# Classpath compiles correctly, but will not run. What am I missing

Tags: java, linux, mahout

Greetings,

I'm playing around with [mahout](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/), I've written a basic java class which imports some of the libraries. It seems my classpath is correct when compiling, I get no errors or complaints at all.

However when I run the compiled class I get an exception saying...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
```

Comment: How are you running it? Show your command line.

Comment: javac -cp /home/bob/trunk/core/src/main/java/:/home/bob/javadep/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar:/home/bob/javadep/uncommons-math/:. Test.java

For java I was doing the same with Test instead of Test.java

Comment: why not use `mvn exec:java ...` ? It will setup correct path, etc.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that `.` is not on your classpath. For example, you might be compiling with:

```
javac -cp foo.jar:bar.jar Test.java
```

but then to *run* the code you'd need

```
java -cp foo.jar:bar.jar:. Test
```

The code that you're *compiling* doesn't need to be on the classpath as you're providing the code (so there's nothing to find) - that's why it manages to compile but not run.

That's only a guess, of course - if you could post the commands you're using to compile and run the code, that would help.

Comment: I've tried adding the . as suggested with the java command. I'm now getting an error saying  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory . Would this be due to my classpath being incorrect in someway as it points to the first actual line of code? Javac still works fine.

Comment: p.s java as follows 
javac  -cp /home/bob/trunk/core/src/main/java/:/home/bob/javadep/uncommons-math/:/home/bob/javadep/slf4jx:. Test.java , also t he exact same for java

Comment: @scott: You probably need to refer to the jar file within the slf4jx directory, not just the directory itself. How did you get it to compile before?

Comment: @Jon thats what I've been doing the entire time. I've just removed the entire reference to slf4j (After trying just the JAR and getting the same error). It compiles fine, but obviously wont run using java. Therefore I can at least see my javac is actually not highlighting problems. I'll look into it further. Thanks :)

Comment: @steve: Are you sure you're actually compiling all of your code?

Comment: Hi Jon, Turns out my classpath was just fubar. I cheated and used eclipse to work out if I was doing something wrong. I'll upload the actual classpath as soon as possible.

Comment: @steve, So where did you upload your actual classpath?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm now getting an error saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`

You're missing `slf4j-api.jar` on your class path. With SLF4J, you always need `slf4j-api.jar` and another jar to [bind a logging framework](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#binding). And actually, if you don't care about logging, use `slf4j-nop.jar` instead of `slf4j-log12.jar`.

**Update:** Mahout seems to be available in Maven central repository so using Maven could  ease the class path setup process. And if you're not into learning Maven, consider using [MOP](http://mop.fusesource.org/) which is a command line launcher to run Java stuff that can transparently download Maven artifacts and their dependencies and setup your classpath.

Comment: My latest approach is just dump every single jar into the home dir and use classpath as . , however I did also try your approach as well which threw the 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory


I can only assume that this will be a long process to fix :) and is probably down to mahout using various api's etc.

Comment: @steve `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory` is in `slf4j-api.jar` (at least in the version 1.4.2). Try to use the same version as mahout (i.e. 1.5.8).

Comment: Thanks pascal, i'll check mavan out. I've been using that to run it via jetty but i wanted to write stand alone classes

Answer (score 1):

Compile time classpath sounds right; runtime classpath is wrong.

From the javadocs for that class:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or
>   a ClassLoader instance tries to load
>   in the definition of a class (as part
>   of a normal method call or as part of
>   creating a new instance using the new
>   expression) and no definition of the
>   class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition
>   existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition
>   can no longer be found.

Do you see a Test.class file in the current directory?  Maybe you compiled it to another path by mistake.

Comment: If this is the case, what should i be considering when setting runtime classpath/ I'm using exact same classpath as compile time

Comment: You need a classpath that includes Test.class, obviously.

Comment: Thanks, but class file is in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mahout, be aware that after you build it with Maven, it will generate "*.job" files in the target/ directory, which contain all dependencies packaged together. It is just a .jar file.